# Getting KeyError when parsing JSON in Python for following response

Tags: python, json, list, parsing, dictionary

TL;DR:
Confused on how to parse following JSON response and get the value of [status of 12345 of dynamicValue_GGG of payload] in this case.

Full question:
I get the following as (sanitized) response upon hitting a REST API via Python code below:

> response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload,
>   headers=headers).json()

```
{
    "payload": {
        "name": "asdasdasdasd",
        "dynamicValue_GGG": {
            "12345": {
                "model": "asad",
                "status": "active",
                "subModel1": {
                    "dynamicValue_67890": {
                        "model": "qwerty",
                        "status": "active"
                    },
                "subModel2": {
                    "dynamicValue_33445": {
                        "model": "gghjjj",
                        "status": "active"
                    },
                "subModel3": {
                    "dynamicValue_66778": {
                        "model": "tyutyu",
                        "status": "active"
                    }                   
                }
            }
        },
        "date": "2016-02-04"
    },
    "design": "asdasdWWWsaasdasQ"
}
```

If I do a `type(response['payload'])`, it gives me '`dict`'.

Now, I'm trying to parse the response above and fetch certain keys and values out of it. The problem is that I'm not able to iterate through using "index" and rather have to specify the "key", but then the response has certain "keys" that are dynamically generated and sent over. For instance, the keys called "`dynamicValue_GGG`", "`dynamicValue_66778`" etc are not static unlike the "`status`" key.

I can successfully parse by mentioning like:

```
print response['payload']['dynamicValue_GGG']['12345'][status]
```

in which case I get the expected output = '`active`'.

However, since I have no control on '`dynamicValue_GGG`', it would work only if I can specify something like this instead:

```
print response['payload'][0][0][status]
```

But the above line gives me error: " `KeyError: 0` " when the python code is executed.

Is there someway in which I can use the power of both keys as well as index together in this case?

Comment: Do you know anything about the dynamic value? Does it always start with "dynamicValue_"?

Comment: You can loop over the keys and values of the dictionary, until you get a key that matches the pattern of the dynamic keys.

Comment: Shouldn't `status` be quoted in `['status']`?

Comment: @Barmar Hi.. No, it wouldnt start with dynamicValue. I actually sanitized the real key to give an idea. Usually those values are just numbers like 88266, or alphanumeric. No control over the real data and no pattern either. Thanks.

Comment: Dictionaries don't have any inherent order, you can't use a numeric index to access its elements.

Comment: @Barmar - [status] works (no quotes). But that part was fine. I was concerned over the keyError 0, when i got with index numbers. If i explicitly mention the real key there (alphanumeric value), then the code just works.

Comment: So they just stick these random keys into the JSON, along with keys like `name` and `date`? I guess you could check whether it's one of those static keys, and if it's not then it must be the dynamic key.

Comment: @Barmar. True. But still wondering how to parse the response to get value of [status of 12345 of dynamicValue_GGG of payload] in this case. :(

Comment: What does the dynamic key represent? It must have some meaning, and I suspect you can use that to determine the key to look up.

Comment: name and date are all static, those keys never change. But few of the other keys where i have mentioned "dynamicValue_*" are examples of keys that vary in each response. As in, the response itself is not a full set of fixed keys; the keys themselves can be different between the responses.

Comment: Look up may not be an option here, as i have very limited view into the possible keys that can come in, especially so considering future cases.

Comment: They must be something you can look up from some other part of the API, like a company ID, transaction ID, etc. I find it hard to believe that the API would just insert random keys in the response and expect any client application to be able to parse them.

Comment: I suspect you haven't shown the JSON accurately. In the `12345` object, you have three `subModel:` properties, but keys have to be unique. There's probably just a single `subModels:` property, whose value is an array. Maybe all the dynamic values are in a single object, that makes it easier to parse.

Comment: Try posting the actual JSON instead of sanitizing it, because you've obviously messed it up when you were doing that.

Comment: You are right.. there is only one subModel but it has an array of values with 3 keys that have dynamic values in them (and unique). Sorry not to post the actual response, but I will correct it now. Thanks..

Comment: @Barmar - for simplicity, i have renamed them as subModel1, subModel2 .. the structure is now correct.

Comment: You just said that there's only one `subModel` and it contains an array. But that's not what you show in the corrected JSON. Please just post the real JSON.

Comment: There *has* to be some other API you can call to get the dynamic value. Otherwise there's just no reasonable way to process this response.

Comment: Barmar - thanks for taking time to analyze this question. I agree that sanitizing the json messed up some of the structure. But there was a general problem with keys being dynamic, which I really suspect is valid JSON being returned. I followed the logic @ferry boender posted below, and was able to tweak it with additional code to solve this problem. It was tough parsing through, but the logic was good to get things down. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of values in a dictionary in Python are random, so you cannot use indexing. You'll have to iterate over all elements, potentially recursive, and test to see if it's the thing you're looking for. For example:

```
def find_submodels(your_dict):
  for item_key, item_values in your_dict.items():
    if 'status' in item_values:
      print item_key, item_values['status']

    if type(item_values) == dict:
      find_submodels(item_values)

find_submodels(your_dict)
```

Which would output:

```
12345 active
dynamicValue_67890 active
dynamicValue_66778 active
dynamicValue_33445 active
```

Comment: `status` is 2 levels down from the dynamic value. It should be `if 'status' in item_values['12345']:`

Comment: Also, you should test whether `item_values` is a dict before you use `if 'status' in item_values:`. You don't want to do that on the `name` and `date` items, since their values are strings.

Comment: This code is obviously not fool proof. It's merely a demonstration of how to iterate through dynamic hierarchical data. The OP's posted data isn't even valid Python, so it's probably going to be different in his real problem.

Comment: It's not supposed to be valid Python, it's JSON.

Comment: The user clearly indicates: "type(response['payload']), it gives me 'dict'.", so it's a Python data structure, parsed from JSON. Do we really need to get into needless discussions here?

Comment: Thanks Barmar and Ferry Boender for looking into this. I followed Ferry's suggested code and was able to parse further through the dynamic code. Had to use if elif else to parse down the tree of dynamic values, but the idea was same. Thanks again!